# ImageView Slider horizontally

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to create a horizontal slider of images fitted in my imageview in  my main layout file. But instead of imageview sliding on touch, the code is moving the whole layout horizontally.

Following is my Java code for sliding:

```
    public class Artprofile extends FragmentActivity {
        static final int NUM_ITEMS = 5;
        ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e",};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_page);
            imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
        }

       public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
            return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
   }

        public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override

            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutart, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            int position = bundle.getInt("position");
            String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
            int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", "com.example.user.myapplication1");
             imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);
             return swipeView;
          }

           static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return swipeFragment;
           }
       }
   }
```

Following is my main layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/mobileback"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profilewindow1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
    android:id="@+id/layout_mobile1">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    />
  </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the Fragment layout used for sliding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I dont understand the problem. Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: that is what viewpager is for...it slides the whole fragment in `getItem` mehod

Comment: do you mean you need just one image view from R.layout.layoutart being swiped, while other stays in it's place?

Comment: @DmitryBorodin What I want is that I am able to move only image_view1, not the whole layout. The code slides the whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout to wrap imageview and then wrap the layout in horizontal scrollview

Comment: I have already wrapped the imageview into a framelayout, yet no luck

Comment: use linearlayout